# C function condition

Tags: c, if-statement

I have C function:

```
void in_range_3_7(int z) {
   if (3 < z < 7) {
      printf("Yes"); 
   } 
   else { 
      printf("No"); 
   }
}
```

Condition

`if (3 < z < 7)`

always returns 1.

How to make this condition work correctly?

Comment: Try `if (z >= 3 && z <= 7) { ...` for both inclusive.

Comment: You cannot program C (or any other language) by trial and error. Don't _assume_ that the syntax is as you would like it to be.

Comment: `(3 < z < 7)` is the same as `((3 < z) < 7)` where `(3 < z)` results in either `1` (true) or `0` (false). Both values are less than `7`.

Comment: I'll modify @pzaenger's suggestion and recommend `if (3 <= z && z <= 7) {}`